# Creating 2 com_search menu Items in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla3.2, joomla3.1, joomla3.3

I have 2 separate modules for search in joomla ... I want to create 2 com_search menu items and change based on which page these modules are called.

How do I get this to work with / without programming..

Answer (score 0):

If you have already made two modules you should be able to edit each one in the Modules Manager and choose which pages it loads on.

Say you wanted them to both load in the same position, you could tick the homepage for one, save and close it, then open the other and tick all the pages but the homepage.  This way when you looked at the website one search box would show at a time.

Comment: Advanced Module Manager Extension from No Number can help make this easier to assign too